# Fecha y hora de escritura

Tags: sql-server, date, insert

¿Cómo obtengo la fecha y hora del insert de un dato en SQL-Server? La tabla que estoy analizando no tiene fecha y hora en el que se registraron los datos, por lo cual, estoy en búsqueda de una función que me permita obtener la fecha del registro de estos datos. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes que ir a buscarlo al log, si es que hay log....

Comment: Sería un proceso complicado y depende de la configuración de tu servidor para saber si se puede recuperar del log de transacciones. Si ese dato es importante, empiecen por guardar esos datos en la tabla.